# Prox Operator of the Projection to $\mathbb{R}_{+} $

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**Part 001**

Given $  f \left( x \right) = {x}_{+} $.

What would be $ \displaystyle \operatorname{Prox}_{f} \left( x \right) = \operatorname*{argmin}_u \left\{ f \left( u \right) + \frac 1 2 {\left\| u - x \right\|}^{2} \right\} $?

**Part 002**

Now, assuming $ x \in {\mathbb{R}}^{n} $ and $ e \in {\mathbb{R}}^{n} $ where $ e = {\left[ 1, 1, \ldots, 1 \right]}^{T} $.

Defining $ g \left( x \right) = {e}^{T} {x}_{+} $.

What would be $ \displaystyle \operatorname{Prox}_{g} \left( x \right) = \operatorname*{argmin}_u \left\{ g \left( u \right) + \frac 1 2 {\left\| u - x \right\|}^{2} \right\} $?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 001**

If one assume $ u $ is positive, the answer is $ u = x - 1 $ as a minimization of $ u + \frac{1}{2} {\left\| u - x \right\|}^{2} $.

Hence for any $ x \geq 1 $ the answe is $ u = x - 1 $.

For $ x < 0 $ the answer is $ u = x $ since then the cost is zero and this is a non negative cost function.
For $ 0 < x < 1 $ the answer is $ u = 0 $ as $ u $ can't be positive and making it less than zero will gain nothing for the term $ {u}_{+} $ and yet will add for the quadratic term.

**Part 002**

Same idea means:

$$ {u}_{i} = \begin{cases}
{x}_{i} - 1 & \text{ if } {x}_{i} > 1 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } 0 \leq {x}_{i} \leq 1 \\ 
{x}_{i} & \text{ if } {x}_{i} < 0
\end{cases} $$

Both results can be verified using the identity:

$$ x - u \in \partial f \left( u \right), \; u = \displaystyle \operatorname{Prox}_{f} \left( x \right) $$

Where the Sub Gradient of each is given by:

$$ c = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \leq 0 \\ 
1 & \text{ if } 0 < x
\end{cases} \in \partial f \left( x \right) , \quad d \in \partial g \left( x \right) \; \text{s .t. } \; {d}_{i} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } {x}_{i} \leq 0 \\ 
1 & \text{ if } 0 < {x}_{i}
\end{cases} $$

Pay attention that in Part 001 the function is a scalar function.

Michael Grant,
I saw you answered as well (While I was typing).
Since you were first, please bring your answer back so I will be able to mark it.

Thank You.